# Manipulating JSON using pig

Tags: json, hadoop, macros, apache-pig, bigdata

**Input file (ABC.txt):-**

> {"rollno":"10000232","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"peter","qualification":"eng","Address1":"block 3", "Address2":"lane 5","City":"california","zipcode":"10021"}
>
> {"rollno":"10000223","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"john","qualification":"doc","Address1":"block 2", "Address2":"lane 2", "City": "california","zipcode":"10021"}
>
> {"rollno":"10000432","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"jim","qualification":"eng","Address1":"block 1","Address2":"lane 1","City":"california","zipcode":"10021"}
>
> {"rollno":"10000523","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"trek","qualification":"doc","Address1":"block 2", "Address2":"lane 2", "City": "california","zipcode":"10021"}
>
> {"rollno":"10000632","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"peter","qualification":"eng","Address1":"block 6", "Address2": "lane 6", "City": "california","zipcode":"10021"}

Business Rule -

(1) Write two Pig Macros as follow:- 
     - Concatenate Address1, Address2, City
     - First 6 digit of RollNo
 Note: Macro as they will be reused across script

(2) Print all fields : 
      A = Load 'abc.txt' using JsonStorage

(3) Delete Address1, Address2, City and Replace it with concatenate from step 1

(4) Delete Rollno. and replace it with step1 output

Idea is to have a configurable approach as the step1 (Macros) will be used across many scripts.
Want to do this without hardcoding field names. Idea is to have code that can be reused for multiple input files.

many thanks for help

Comment: is this a: "please do my homework for me" question?

Comment: No Havnar, but want to understand if one can do it without hardcoding, thanks for your help

Comment: well ... the answer is "yes", just write a pig script to read the adress fields and rollno etc, and write in the order you like. you might want to use a jsonparser.

Comment: Please refer to the question. I am not looking to hardcode the field name and that is where the help is required. Writing a pig script to read the fields is No big deal.